# Clang compiler (x86): 80 bit long double

Tags: c++, x86, clang, x87, long-double

I'm trying to use native 80 bit long double on x86 Windows platform.  [The GCC option `-mlong-double-80`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html) doesn't seem to work with clang.  I tried

```
clang -target i386-windows -mlong-double-80 -c -O3 "test.c"
```

But the compiler shows me the error:

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mlong-double-80'
```

Comment: ICC has [`/Qlong-double` on Windows](https://software.intel.com/en-us/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-qlong-double), but I didn't find any indication that clang supports it either.  It might be that clang simply doesn't have that option on Windows, or maybe you'd have to manually use [GNU C `__float80`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Floating-Types.html) if clang supports that.  I don't have Windows clang to test with.

Comment: On Clang unfortunately: `error: unknown type name '__float80'`. But should I include some file?

Comment: No, I think if it was supported at all it would be like `int` and you could just use it.  A double-underscore name like `__float80` *is* the internal name that a header file might define other things in terms of.

Comment: So should I change the target to another x86?

Comment: Well i386-linux-gnu uses the i386 System V ABI which specifies 80-bit `long double` .  If you can change to a different x86 ABI, yes that would work.  But I thought you wanted your code to work on x86 Windows, presumably using Windows DLLs with their struct layouts.  If you meant 64-bit mode, I doubt that would help with *this*, although it's generally better for performance unless your data structures are very pointer-heavy.  If you meant a different compiler (like GCC), then yes that would work too.

Comment: My compiler needs COFF objects, but i386-linux-gnu ELF emits :(. Yes, I need to compile objects under Win32, and I need an 80 bit double. But maybe I incorrectly configured the target, architecture or other parameters.

Comment: The Windows ABI uses 64-bit `long double`.  That's a choice MS made; changing that would be ABI-breaking for any code that passed around `long double` objects.  It's certainly possible that clang doesn't have an option for it.  I only suggested a different ABI because you brought up the idea of changing to a different x86 target.

Comment: @PeterCordes [clang does support `-mlong-double-80`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#long-double-flags)

Comment: clang uses 80-bit long double by default, but somehow when I use the flag `-mlong-double-80` it emits that strange error https://godbolt.org/z/Xd3yfh

Comment: This is an example of two platforms: https://godbolt.org/z/fxdDVT

Comment: So...  i386-windows-gnu target solves the problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: [How does GCC compile the 80 bit wide 10 byte float \_\_float80 on x86\_64?](//stackoverflow.com/q/49909914) mentions `_Float64x` (80-bit float with 64-bit mantissa).  Linux clang supports that typename only if you `#include <math.h>` so IDK if it could help on Windows.

Comment: Thank. But in this case we are talking only about x86.